# Armature not staying in place

Tags: rigging, armature

For some reason I'm not getting, the armature for the arms aren't staying in place when I move the root bone. I've added weights though, and they have vertex groups, so I'm not sure what's wrong. They just seem to 'fold' whenever I move the whole character.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? Why should the arm bones stay in place if you move the root? Maybe you meant something else?

Comment: Sorry, I have worded it wrong. Basically the armature doesn't move with the arms; they fall out. I've added a save to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you first need to make some armature corrections :

- Rotate your IK controller in *Edit* mode to make it more easy to handle.
- Deactivate its *Deform* option as it is not supposed to influence the mesh.
- Unparent it, it is not supposed to be child of the hand, it is supposed to be parented with offset to the root bone.
- Select the hand and make it the child of the controller.
- You may also need to move the *Pole Target*, and also deactivate *Deform*.

Now when you select the mesh in *Weight Paint* mode, you can see that the chest bone influences the arms while it is not supposed to, so use the brush to correct that.

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I've followed your steps, but it's still doing the same thing. :-\